# How to with open() several files into the same array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I created a program that added integers from a file into an array and then did something to them, but when I tried to add two files into the same array the code I was using didn't work. Here's the code I used for one file which worked fine:

```
with open(files) as f:
        prime_list1 = [int(i) for line in f for i in line.split()]
```

But when I tried adding a second file, what I did din't work.

```
with open(files) as f, open(files2) as b:
        prime_list1 = [int(i) for line in f for i in line.split() + int(i) for line in b for i in line.split()]
```

I know that that is not how you do it, I just couldn't figure out the correct way. I also realize that there already exists similar questions, but their answers did not work in my case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to concatenate two lists?

Comment: @vaultah No I don't

Comment: You should start reading a Python tutorial then. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: @vaultah Ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost - you can do it as two separate list comprehensions,

```
[int(i) for line in f for i in line.split()] + [int(i) for line in b for i in line.split()]
#                                          ^   ^
```

Answer (score -1):

Just define your files in a list, loop through the list, open, read, convert to ints and, finally, concatenate them:

```
files = ["file1", "file2"] # etc.
result = []
for file_name in files:
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        result += [int(i) for line in f for i in line.split()]
```